# Can't get current page to add active class to nav item in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, safari

I am trying to add a class of "is-active-page" to the header navigation list item belonging to the page the user is currently on. What I have works (even in IE), but for some reason Safari isn't accepting the active class on the li. No idea why. Any help would be great.

```
 $(".nav-list li a").filter(function(){
  return this.href === window.location.href;
}).parent("li").addClass('is-active-page');
```

Comment: Add a `console.log(this.href, window.location.href)` inside the .filter to see what's going on (or use other debugging tools to check).  It may be that one or the other is dropping the `https://`

Answer (score 1):

The `window.location.href` returns back the whole url of your website. For example `https://yoursite.com/somelink`

While most probably in your case your `hrefs` are linking to `/somelink`.

You can change the return statement to the 2 possible ways below:

1.

```
var url = window.location.href.split('/');
var link = this.href; 
var item = link.substring(1, link.length); // remove the slash in the beginning 
return this.href == url[url.length - 1]; // I don't think you need ===
```

2. 

```
return window.location.href.contains(this.href);
```